# Google Play console : "impossible to specify a price in BRL for Brazil" => impossible to save modifications

Tags: android, console, google-play

I have got a problem with one of my paid apps. I cannot save any modification because there is a problem with the price defined for Brazil. Below the screenshot of what I can see (in French sorry). I don't understand why it is written "impossible to define a price in BRL for Brazil".

The problem is that I cannot save any modification made to my metadata, because of this problem. Even if I remove Brazil from my countries (by unchecking the checkbox), the same error is displayed and I am unable to save any modification or upload any new apk.

Any idea how I can solve this ?

Thanks !

[image: What I see in Google Play console]

Comment: I can't see your screen shot, are you perhaps setting the price below the minimum amount the store will accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there was probably a bug of the console... I simply clicked on the button "Convert the prices automatically" (I don't know if is the exact translation, my console is in French) and it solved the issue !

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it because you´re adding 0% of tax on the sale?

Brazil is on the list of countries on which you have to shown the final price to the consumer, inclusing tax, and you´re not including any tax on that price...

link: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138000?hl=en